# nested group by in LINQ give me "The LINQ expression could not be translated"

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-7.0, ef-core-7.0

this query for make list of department every department have list of Employees then every employee has list of data about his attendance
for that I use nested group in multiple layer then use nested select to display data but i get error ""The LINQ expression  could not be translated"
then i use group in one layer then use select , into select i use group by then select but also get the same error
i don't Know what is the wrong part in my code

```cs
public async Task<dynamic> GetPermissionByDept(DateTime fromDay, DateTime toDay)
{
    return await (
        from perm in _db.Permissions.Include(p => p.PermissionType)
                                    .Include(p => p.Employee).ThenInclude(e => e.OrgUnit)

        where perm.DayDate >= fromDay && perm.DayDate <= toDay
        where perm.Employee.IsActive && perm.IsApproved

        let department = _db.OrgUnits
                            .Where(o => perm.Employee.OrgUnit.Hid.IsDescendantOf(o.Hid) && o.Hid.GetLevel() <= 3)
                            .OrderByDescending(o => o.Hid.GetLevel())
                            .Select(o => o.Name)
                            .FirstOrDefault()
        group new
        {
            Employee = new EmployeeWithDept(perm.Employee, department),
            DepartmentName = department,
            PermissionType = perm.PermissionType.Name,
            perm.DayDate,
            perm.FromTime,
            perm.ToTime,
            PermMinutes = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(perm.ToTime.Subtract(perm.FromTime).TotalMinutes),
        }
        by department into deptGroup

        from empGroup in
        (
            from department in deptGroup
            group department by department.Employee
        )
        group empGroup by deptGroup.Key into empData

        select new
        {
            empData.Key,
            EmployeeDetails = empData.Select(p => new
            {
                p.Key.FullNameAr,
                p.Key.FullNameEn,
                TotalMinutes = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(p.Sum(x => x.PermMinutes.TotalMinutes)),
                PermissionCount = p.Count(),
                Permissions = p.Select(x => new
                {
                    x.PermissionType,
                    x.DayDate,
                    x.FromTime,
                    x.ToTime,
                    x.PermMinutes
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList()
        })
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as "nested groups" in SQL. Using `ToList()` to cover up problems in the query is no solution. Runtime errors are the *best* case. Worst case is loading entire tables in memory, causing problems for the entire application and *all users*

Comment: EF tries to translate the *entire* query into SQL. That means that you have to remove all elements that can't be translated into SQL. Are you using `SqlHierarchyId`? If so, please mention such essential details.

Comment: This query has a *lot* of calls that could result in this error. For starters, there's **no hierarchyid support** in EF Core 7. It was added in [EF Core 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/hierarchyid?tabs=netcore-cli). Using the SqlHierarchyID type in a property wont' make EF Core generate the proper SQL code by itself. `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(p.Sum(x => x.PermMinutes.TotalMinutes))` is another thing that can't be translated to `sql`. There's no equivalent to `TimeSpan` and `time` is only the time of day, not a duration

Comment: I know there's a NuGet package with a name that suggests it's somehow part of EF Core. It's not. It's a third-party package from someone that systematically used official-sounding names until NuGet cracked down on this.

Comment: Finally, such a large LINQ query is a *clear* sign you're doing it wrong. The main actor is EF, an ORM, not LINQ, its query language. An ORM's job is to give the impression of working with in-memory objects instead of tables and rows, *NOT* allow you to embed SQL in your code. If the query starts getting that complicated either the relations are wrong, or your *entities* are wrong. It would be better to create a view or function with the complex SQL query and map your (possibly new) entities to that view

Comment: Try `(TimeSpan)(p.Sum(x => x.PermMinutes.TotalMinutes) / 60 / 24)`

Comment: I use ```EntityFramworkcore.SqlServer.HierarchyId```
thsi a good to explain using query of it
https://www.meziantou.net/using-hierarchyid-with-entity-framework-core.htm
@GertArnold

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos
yes i use ```EntityFramworkcore.SqlServer.HierarchyId``` and it is a thisd party not part of EF core but I use it in many part of project and translate to SQL is working fine

Comment: @Charlieface
I am commint all TimeSpan in query but still has the same errror